# Is this a correct way to validate a login?

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I was wondering is the following method to validate is a user can login or not is correct, tecnically it works, I've tried it and it does what I wanted but this is the first time I do this on Java and I wanted to make sure I was not violating any important conventions.

What this method does is:

1. Receives a loginRequest, loginResponse and a HttpSession.
2. Fetch a user based on the email (which I have to find a way to make
   sure it doesn't repeat on user registration)
3. Gets the user's status
4. Compares the input password within the request with the user's
   digest on the database.

Finally; If they match and the user is active it may
    access the aplication.

Is there anything I'm missing? Especifically:

Do I have to include any throw;catch?
Is the user's details vulnerable because I get his info with just his email and then compare?

**Method:**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void checkUser(LoginRequest lr, LoginResponse response, HttpSession currentSession) {

    Usuario loggedUser = loginRepository.findByEmail(lr.getEmail());
    isActive = loggedUser.getIsActiveUs();

    if (encryptor.match(lr.getPassword(), loggedUser.getPassword())) {

            if(isActive){
                response.setCode(200);
                response.setCodeMessage("User authorized");

                //CREATE AND SET THE VALUES FOR THE CONTRACT OBJECT
                response.setUserId(loggedUser.getIdUsuario());
                response.setFirstName(loggedUser.getName());
                response.setLastName(loggedUser.getLastName());
                //response.setIdTenant(loggedUser.getIdTenant().getIdTenant());

                currentSession.setAttribute("userId", loggedUser.getIdUsuario());
            }else{
                response.setCode(400);
                response.setErrorMessage("User is inactive, please contact your admin.");

            }

        } else {
            response.setCode(401);
            response.setErrorMessage("Unauthorized User");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's the reason behind of NOT using Spring Security instead?

Comment: @Branislav Lazic This little school project is based on a template given to us, the login was already done like this but with a lot of errors which we had to "fix".  I'll check into Spring securitu to see if it is easier to use and implement. May as well do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to include any throw;catch?

most likely yes, at least your `loginRepository` is one of candidats, as it probably goes to DB to get data (depending from how it is implemented).

> Is the user's details vulnerable because I get his info with just his email and then compare?

Please clarify, what do you mean by "vulnerable"? (more than one user with same email, security reasons ...)

Remarks to code:

- LoginResponse should be method's return type instead of void. Output argument is bad code style
- I did that part of application with Spring a couple of times, but I haven't seen such way to check user login. Maybe you ought to google for some how-tos or provide us with yuor motivation to do that in thia way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes my main concer is that more than one user will have the same email. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: To take care of unique email constraint (If you are going to use Spring security), you can specify custom @Entity class for user and mark email field with @Column(unique= true).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.